# click on a link does not take me to the intended page. From the Murach PHP book

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I'm very new to  php and I'm going over the Murach PHP book. I'm having a problem with clicking on a link in the categories section because when it clicks on the link it ads `?category_id=3` but the problem is it  adds it after `add_product.php` like-> `http://localhost/my_murach_php/add_product.php?category_id=3`

I want it to add after `http://localhost/my_murach_php/` so it looks like `http://localhost/my_murach_php/?category_id=3`

I am able to see the categories when i click on the links before I do anything with adding products.
I could see the category info on the index page and when I click on it from the index page
I get to go to `http://localhost/my_murach_php/add_product_form.php` (good) to add a product I click on the button and it takes me to `http://localhost/my_murach_php/add_product.php`(good) then when I click a category I get this page `http://localhost/my_murach_php/add_product.php?category_id=1` (not good) I would like it to be this page `http://localhost/my_murach_php/?category_id=3`

Here's how I Included the link on the index page

```
        <li>
            <a href="?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $category['categoryName']; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
```

I have `include("index.php");` in the add_product.php file

I guess the problem is going back to the root directory when I am on the `http://localhost/my_murach_php/add_product.php?category_id=1` page.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how this is related to MySQL. But I also don't understand your question. You've found out that the link is wrong, and you've found the part that generates it. Where are your stuck? Just including another `php` file isn't going to change how that link is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a href like "?category_id=..." then the browser assumes you just want to add this to your CURRENT url. So to go to the url you want, just use the full url you need, like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/my_mutach_php?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
```

Btw. `<?php echo` can be written as `<?=` to make it simpler and more readable.

Comment: this solves the problem. I just thought I didn't have to right http://localhost/my_mutach_php because I didn't need to do that to view the categories when I clicked on the links on the index page. thanks for explaining that it just adds it on to the url.